# How to add facebook share to Android app

Tags: java, android, facebook-sharer

As the title reads, I am unsure how to add a share function to my Android app, and my brother tells me older methods of Facebook sharing are no longer officially supported, so the older tutorials are effectively out of date? As a result I can't find any up-to-date tutorials on how to use the Facebook SDK & add a share function.

The Facebook dev site may prove useful once I wrap my head more around Android developing (I'm still new), but in the meanwhile, does anyone have any links to up-to-date tutorials (text or video) on how to add a Facebook share option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use the official developers site of Facebook?

Pretty easy to find something on it.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share << On this site you can learn how to share.

The keypart is this:

```
FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this)
    .setLink("https://developers.facebook.com/android")
    .build();
uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
```

Don't forget to download and add the sdk to your application: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/

Good luck, if you need any explanation write a comment to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should just implement a share intent instead and let the system do it all for you.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
            android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
            android:title="Share"
            android:actionProviderClass=
                "android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
    ...
</menu>
```

and

```
private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
...

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate menu resource file.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.share_menu, menu);

    // Locate MenuItem with ShareActionProvider
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

    // Fetch and store ShareActionProvider
    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();

    // Return true to display menu
    return true;
}

// Call to update the share intent
private void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) {
    if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "let the system do it for you"? How does this differ from using a share dialog? Does it need permissions? Sorry for the questions, you can tell I'm new (Y)

Comment: The share intent/dialog allows the user to choose what network, aswell as the option of facebook, you can assign in your app what you want them to share with it.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, the best way to learn about the use of the Facebook SDK is on the [Facebook Developer's site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/sample-apps).

I haven't used the samples recently but I did run into troubles (about a year ago) while implementing different features and to be honest, their support isn't stellar: at the time it was basically "Go ask your questions on stackoverflow".

So, if you want to simplify your life and your programming, I recommend using the [Simple Facebook Library](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook) available on GitHub. It's pretty up-to-date and much less convoluted than coding your own version.